# Add EditText in android using cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am developing in cocos2d-android. I am facing a problem with integrating EditText in a CCScene. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Use Dialog for this ...

Answer (score -1):

pop a framelayout when you click then sprite you want it looks like an edittext
you can draw android view like edittext or btn on it. also you can pop a dialog with an edittext on it.